# is Linuxfxversion needed while creating a function app and publishing through code not container

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-app-service-plans, azure-function-app

The below snippet is a block from arm template for function app.

```
 "variables": {
        "linuxFxVersion": {
           "python":"DOCKER|microsoft/azure-functions-python3.6:2.0",
           "dotnet":"DOCKER|microsoft/azure-functions-dotnet-core2.0:2.0",
           "node": "DOCKER|microsoft/azure-functions-node8:2.0",
            "java":"",
            "powershell":""
        },
        "FX":"[variables('linuxFxVersion')[parameters('runTimeStack')]]"

    },


{
      "linuxFxVersion": "[if(equals(parameters('osType'),'windows'),json('null'),variables('FX'))]"
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for automating function resource deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-infrastructure-as-code#deploy-on-app-service-plan), the `linuxFxVersion` is required when deploying to a Linux App Service Plan.

When deploying code, you have to use the provided images as in the template that you've shared.

If you are using a custom container, then it should be your container instead as shown in the docs. Here is the same for reference

```
"linuxFxVersion": "DOCKER|myacr.azurecr.io/myimage:mytag"
```